# How to write a Sql statement without using union?

Tags: sql, unions

I have a sql statement like below. How can I add a single row(code = 0, desc = 1) to result of this sql statement without using union keyword? thanks.

```
select code, desc
from material 
where material.ExpireDate ='2010/07/23'
```

Comment: Why not using `UNION`? Interview?

Comment: UNION is sometimes treated badly by DB providers, one example is TClientDataSet + TDataSetProvider in Delphi

Comment: How about a stored procedure returning a result set? Or adding this pseudo-row in the caller code? BTW don't you have a problem using `DESC` as a column name as it already a SQL keyword?

Comment: @pascal-this is a sample. In reality we don' t use desc as a column? I don' t want to give the exact sql statement we use.

Comment: Who downrated the question and why?

Comment: @Mark, Because here only two options: use UNION or use FULL OUTER JOIN with dummy one-row recordset. UNION exists everywhere, so why don't use UNION. Definetelly it is a interview question, and not a real problem. (So I downrated this question too).

Answer (score 3):

You can always create a view for your table which itself uses UNION keyword

```
CREATE VIEW material_view AS SELECT code, desc, ExpireDate FROM material UNION SELECT '0', '1', NULL;
SELECT code, desc FROM material_view WHERE ExpireDate = '2010/07/23' OR code = '0';
```

Comment: No need to `-1`-ing the answer... You did not mention view-avoidance in your question.

Comment: So add a new row to materials with empty date (and other fields) and code '0' and use:
SELECT code, desc FROM material WHERE ExpireDate = '2010/07/23' OR code = '0';

Comment: @mkus - maybe put that in the question?

Comment: @too - Thanks for your qucik response but I can not use your solution.

Answer (score 3):

```
 WITH material   AS
 (
 SELECT * 
 FROM 
      (VALUES (2, 'x', '2010/07/23'), 
              (3, 'y', '2009/01/01'), 
              (4, 'z', '2010/07/23')) vals (code, [desc], ExpireDate)
 )

SELECT 
     COALESCE(m.code,x.code) AS code, 
     COALESCE(m.[desc],x.[desc]) AS [desc]
FROM material m
FULL OUTER JOIN (SELECT 0 AS code, '1' AS [desc] ) x ON 1=0
WHERE m.code IS NULL OR m.ExpireDate ='2010/07/23'
```

Gives

```
code        desc
----------- ----
2           x
4           z
0           1
```

Comment: You could replace the `UNION ALL` with row constructors e.g. `..(VALUES (2, 'x', '2010/07/23'), (3, 'y', '2010/07/23'), (4, 'z', '2010/07/23')) AS material (code, [desc], ExpireDate)...`

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't want to use either a union or a view, I'd suggest adding a dummy row to the material table (with code = 0, desc = 1, and ExpireDate something that would never normally be selected - eg. 01 January 1900) - then use a query like the following:

```
select code, desc
from material 
where material.ExpireDate ='2010/07/23' or 
    material.ExpireDate ='1900/01/01'
```

Normally, a Union would be my preferred option.